# Can I safely mix beef tallow and canola oil in a tabletop fryer with a submersible element?

Tags: deep-frying, beef-tallow, canola-oil

I'm working on Belgium-style frites at home and would like to get as close as possible to the traditional recipe.

I know that they would traditionally be double fried in beef-tallow, but I have a tabletop fryer with a submersible element and I've been cautioned against using any oil that would solidify at room temperature.

Can I safely mix beef tallow and canola oil? If so, will I get enough of the flavoring from the beef tallow?